# What is the name for when genetic deviation results in an organism that doesn't work?

Tags: evolution

There is a word for this, and it's escaping me. I want to reaearch more papers on it, but I can't find them or what the word is called.

It's typically used in the context of fitness and evolution. If there is a dead individual, it doesn't have a fitness and the mutation is called _____. ?? ( in some models could be given a zero or neg inf)

Comment: Hum... it is quite unclear for the moment. All individual have a fitness. Their fitness can be zero though. I am not sure what you mean by "genetic deviation". Do you mean a mutation? Are you looking for an adjective that qualifies a type of mutation, like a "lethal mutation" or maybe "recessive/dominant lethal mutation"?

Comment: Or are you looking for the term 'deleterious'?

Comment: LETHAL. That is the word. They are lethals. Hahah thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## If you are referring to the mutation

I think the word you are looking for is **lethal**.

A lethal mutation is a mutation that causes the death of its carrier. Now there are recessive lethal and dominant lethal. For dominant lethal mutations, all heterozygotes are inviable. For recessive lethal, only double mutant homozygotes are inviable.

## If you are referring to the individual

An individual that is not able to survive and reproduce is said to be **inviable** (I already used the term above). However, the reason for it is not necessarily genetic.

Comment: *lethal* defines the mutation. I believe OP is referring to the whole organism (despite their comment, since the question in the title and in the body are different!)... If that's correct, the word I'd choose is *"inviable"*, which is (almost) in your answer.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thanks, I attempted to clarify that lethal refers to the mutaiton. I also highlighted the use of the term inviable